# Разница между Assembly и Server в Blazor

Tags: .net, веб-программирование, asp.net-core, blazor

Вопрос, чтобы понять разницу между Сервером и Сборкой в Блазор и использовать все привелегии фреймворков верно.

Вот сравнение, которое дает документация.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите разобрать список, того, что мне лично не понятно:

> Встроенный SignalR.
>
> Используйте байт-код для передачи данных между
> серверной частью и интерфейсом.

> Используйте JSON для передачи данных между API и интерфейсом.
>
> Можно использовать безсерверную модель хостинга.

Я по моим раскопкам начала читать, где то прочитала по RSignal, что если много пользователей, много запросов, тогда как wasm ведет расчет в браузере. Это важно, если например много юзеров и постоянные расчеты к примеру.

а по другим пунктам, там даже не знаю как в поиск и что вбивать, чтоб читать.

от себя из практики скажу, что Сервер как стандартный веб сайт, довольно прост, быстро загружается в сравнении с wasm. В целом они почти одинаковые (?)

Comment: Блазор сервер - вся логика выполняется на сервере, взаимодействие с клиентом (браузером) происходит через websocket (на самом деле через функциональность библиотеки SignalR которая абстрагирует от специфики протокола)
Байт-код - бинарные сериализованные данные
Веб-сборка блазор - весь код выполняется на клиенте, но на клиенте нет БД поэтому для взаимодействия с БД придётся делать отдельное веб приложение которому мы будем отправлять данные (например в формате JSON) для сохранения в БД.

Comment: @Nikolay Байт-код - бинарные сериализованные данные ===> а что это дает ? Wasm есть БД IndexedDb https://blazorschool.com/tutorial/blazor-wasm/dotnet6/indexeddb-storage-749869

Comment: а правда ли, что вот например у меня магазин, я считаю сток, и сто продавцов....все они открывают закрывают, считают отправляют...и вот васм лучше тем, что меньше ходит туда сюда. все сам делает. а сервер как вы и сказали через сигнал эР берет. И что какие привелегии? если честно пока я только плюсы в сервере вижу. У меня васм оооооочень долго открыввается.....белая страница висит...... а сервер летает

Comment: Видимо эти слова просто маркетинг, наверно хотели сказать что мы используем более компактную сериализацию для обмена сообщениями с сервером чем просто json
IndexedDb - а вы читали что это такое? это БД внутри вашего браузера. Если нет необходимости центрального хранилища данных то можно ограничится этой БД

Comment: @Nikolay я не только читала, но даже тестировала. Пока ищу способ айДи отоЖенерейт, чтоб не прописывать айДи для каждого юзера. По тому, что я читала эта база достаточно секюризирована, но вот само то, что в браузере она хранится......для настроек пользователя можно, но там кстати указано что один домен не может видеть базу другого домена....

Comment: скажите, а вы давно с блазором работаете ?

Comment: Я бы не стал строгать blazor, т.к. есть устоявшиеся технологии типа mvc. У майкрософта есть не хорошая особенность хоронить свои "перспективные" разработки. Блазор является одной из таких "перспективных" разработок, как например в своё время silverlight

Comment: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/blazor-server-vs-blazor-web-assembly/

Comment: По поводу интернет магазина на Blazor,  если вам нужна SEO для страниц вашего интернет магазина,  то есть в поисковой выдаче должны ранжироваться запросы для конкретного товара,  тогда для вас лучше схема SSR,  то есть Blazor-Server, так как в таком случае ваши страницы будут быстрее загружаться, но Blazor-Server работает через SignalR, а значит пока клиент рассматривает страницу товара, для этого клиента должно поддерживаться активное соединение, что нагружает ресурсы сервереа.

Comment: По поводу магазина на Blazor, смотрите вот этот [плейлист](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLePGPxR0FDm9j8KObf8QcaknQQqPO6p0X).  О том что такое SignalR, смотрите вот [здесь](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLePGPxR0FDm8yroElV52ikUZu6IE_9bZX).

Comment: @AndreiBrizhak классно, гляну. Я заметила еще в другом вопросе ваш комментарий https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1536166/net-ui-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b1-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80?noredirect=1#comment2764044_1536166 это ваши курсы ? там ссылка на юдеми вроде

Comment: @AndreiBrizhak это человек, или робот говорит ? Я очень хочу посмотреть, пришлось включить субтитры, но это ооооочень сложно.  [Вертер](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zGVcu.jpg)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/training/modules/build-blazor-webassembly-visual-studio-code/

Answer (score 0):

[перевод книги Блазор](https://habr.com/ru/companies/jugru/articles/772646/) (вот [тут](https://dmkpress.com/catalog/computer/web/978-5-93700-179-5/) лично я преобрела книгу, перевод качественный и очень понятный)

исходя из источников, хотелось бы тут обозначить разницу, как ее трактуют в книге.

Wasm:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

поскольку приложения Blazor WebAssembly – это просто статические файлы, их
можно развернуть в  любом месте, где доступен хостинг данного вида файлов. Это открывает возможности, которые ранее никогда не были доступны разработчикам .NET. Такие сервисы, как страницы GitHub, Netlify, Azure Blob Storage, контейнеры объектов AWS (Amazon Web Services) S3 и Azure Static Web
Apps, – все это варианты размещения автономных приложений
Blazor WebAssembly. Стоимость развертывания статических
файлов у всех ведущих поставщиков облачных сервисов ниже
по сравнению с размещением веб-приложений;

Server:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

страница на хостинге для приложения Blazor Server – это
Razor Page, а не статическая HTML-страница, как в модели WebAssembly. Преимущество данного подхода в том, что он позволяет приложениям Blazor Server использовать предварительный рендеринг
на стороне сервера из коробки. Фактически эта функция включается
по умолчанию при создании такого типа Blazor-приложения.
Как только первоначальная полезная нагрузка передается в браузер, файлы обрабатываются и создается DOM, а затем выполняется
файл blazor.server.js. Задача этой среды выполнения – установить обратное подключение SignalR к приложению Blazor, работающему на
сервере.

**про сигнал R :**

SignalR – это библиотека с  открытым исходным кодом от компании
Microsoft, позволяющая разработчикам добавлять в свои приложения
функциональность реального времени.

Клиенты подключаются к серверу через хаб, после чего сервер отправляет обновления клиентам в реальном времени с помощью веб-сокетов (или другой подходящей технологии). Распространенный пример использования SignalR – создание приложения для чата.
Хотя SignalR может быть использован отдельно,
в Blazor он применяется для передачи событий и обновлений пользовательского интерфейса между клиентом и сервером, и в данном случае
SignalR считается деталью реализации фреймворка, поэтому разработчику, работающему с  Blazor Server, не требуется настраивать его или
как-то взаимодействовать с ним.

> добавлю по личному опыту, какие выводы я сделала, после тестирования.
>
> васм долго загружается (видна белая страница секунд 30, особенно первый
> раз. пока загрузит кеш), возможно это скоро исправят, на сегодняшний
> день, приложения на блазор очень тяжелые...
>
> сервер очень хорошо работает (иногда бывают обрывы, если подключение
> интернета не константное, но быстро реабилитируется и
> переподключается), есть приложение на сервер, используется клиентами,
> работает активно и четко. Самое приятное, что можно писать все на
> шарпе. Я бы сравнила сервер на простом языке с обычным сайтом, к
> примеру на php. Все-таки хочется отметить, что к примеру сайты продаж к примеру лучше не рисковать создавать на сервер на сегодняшний день. Транзакция если оборвется, то возникнут неудобства.

p.s.этот ответ я планирую дополнять