# .NET UI веб-сервер

Tags: c#, asp.net, mvc, веб-сервер, asp-net-core-mvc

У меня есть UI для проекта, там чисто папка с файлами фронта. Используется обычные .html-файлы. Можно ли как-то настроить ASP.NET (ну или WEB API) так же, как работают фреймворки на других платформах, т.е., например, чтобы при запросе какого-то файла, сервер заглядывал в мою папку с UI и пытался взять его оттуда.
Типа у меня есть папка UI (которая должна считаться корнем фронта), там файл index.html и файл details.html в папке UI/core. Хочу чтобы при заходе на страницу http://myservice/index.html открывался index.html, а на http://myservice/core/details.html, открывался details.html. Аналогично с доп. ресурсами типа стилей и js-кода.
Также чтобы я мог настроить какой-нибудь роутинг, например, http://myservice сразу открывает index.html.
На текущий момент я написал велосипед: просто сделал 1 метод контроллера MVC и все запросы перенаправляю на него, а дальше он парсит url, читает файл, определяет ContentType и возвращает Content(). Выглядит не очень, возможно, вы знаете какое-то более изящное решение?

Comment: возможно вам подойдет просто настроить [static files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

Comment: @ExplodingKitten, спасибо. А что насчет роутинга? Можно ли как-то перенаправлять некоторые запросы (урлы или url-паттерны) на файлы без редиректа?

Comment: Посмотрите [плейлист](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLePGPxR0FDm_HvURobtaz8GrLaI-iQhhc), где для проекта на ASP.NET MVC,  в том числе, настраивается маршрутизация к статическим файлам.